# Cannot match dynamic routes like /recipes/:id/ingredients

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I am using the npm package `react-router-dom@4.0.0-beta.6` for my react app.

I am able to match routes like:

- `/trends`
- `/news`
- `/recipes`

But I can't match routes like:

- `/recipes/:id/ingredients` or `/recipes/1234/ingredients`

If I switch from `/recipes/1234` to `/recipes/1234/ingredients` I only match the route `/recipes/:id` but not `/recipes/:id/ingredients`.

The app looks like this:

```
const factory = (name, path) => {
  return (props) => {
    const { children, match, routes } = props;
    const { params } = match;

    // convert the child routes from /recipes/:id/ingredients to /recipes/1234/ingredients
    const others = routes.map(x => pathToRegexp.compile(x.path)(params));

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{name}</h3>

        <ul>
          {others.map(x =>
            <Link key={x} to={x}>{x}</Link>
          )}
        </ul>

        {children}
      </div>
    );
  };
};

const rootPattern = '/recipes/:id';

const routes = [
  {
    path: rootPattern,
    component: factory('Root', rootPattern),
    routes: [
      {
        path: `${rootPattern}/ingredients`,
        component: factory('Ingredients', `${rootPattern}/ingredients`),
      },
      {
        path: `${rootPattern}/steps`,
        component: factory('Steps', `${rootPattern}/steps`),
      },
    ],
  },
];

// wrap <Route> and use this everywhere instead, then when
// sub routes are added to any route it'll work
const RouteWithSubRoutes = (route) => (
  <Route path={route.path} render={props => (
    // pass the sub-routes down to keep nesting
    <route.component {...props} routes={route.routes}/>
  )}/>
);

const RouteConfigExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/recipes/1234">Sandwiches</Link></li>
      </ul>

      {routes.map((route, i) => (
        <RouteWithSubRoutes key={i} {...route}/>
      ))}
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

To be fair I don't really understand why my app doesn't match the dynamic routes.

You can find a complete example at https://github.com/jbrieske/react-router-config.

Comment: Your actual routing pattern looks like 

`/sandwiches/:id/:cat`
or

`/sandwiches/:id/*`